# Fourier transform computation

Tags: integration

Here is a very interesting integral computation problem (see the attached picture):

$$\int_0^\infty J_1(|\xi|r)2r^2\mu^2(3\mu^2-6\mu r^2+r^4)(\mu+r^2)^{-8} dr.$$

Here $J_1$ is the Bessel J function with index 1 (see [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Definitions) for an explicit definition, including a series expansion).

More backgournd on why we should care about this:
According to *Radial functions and the Fourier transform* ([PDF](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Efaris/methodsweb/hankel.pdf)):
this notes, this is equivalent to taking Fourier transform on 4 dimensional Euclidean space, with respect to the integrand, but now consider it as a spherically symmetric function parameterized by r.
Context: this question arise from the AdS/CFT correspondence, this is the Fourier transform of the AdS gravity bubbling's first order potential. Due to the limitation of length, I can not offer full explanation here, but all details can be found at the introduction of [Bubbling AdS and droplet descriptions of BPS geometries in IIB supergravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2233).

Current progress and possible stategy: this might be related to some special function like hypergeometric function etc..?

Answer (score 0):

This integral can be decomposed into three components:

$$
I = 6\mu^4 \underbrace{\int_0^{\infty} J_1(|\xi|r) \frac{r^2}{(\mu+r^2)^8}\, \mathrm{d}r}_{I_1} - 12\mu^3 \underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}J_1(|\xi|r) \frac{r^3}{(\mu + r^2)^8}\, \mathrm{d}r}_{I_2} + 2\mu^2 \underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}J_1(|\xi|r) \frac{r^6}{(\mu+r^2)^8}\, \mathrm{d}r}_{I_3}
$$

From Fletcher, A., Miller, J. C. P., and Rosenhead, L., *An Index of Mathematical Tables*, 2nd ed., You might be able to use this formula:

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha -1}}{(x^2+z^2)^{\rho}} J_{\mu}(cx)J_{\nu}(cx) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{c}{2}\right)^{2\rho-\alpha}\\[.2cm]
\times{}&{}  \Gamma \left[\begin{matrix} \frac{\mu+\nu+\alpha}{2} -\rho, 1+2\rho-\alpha\\ \frac{\mu-\nu-\alpha}{2}+\rho+1, \frac{\mu+\nu-\alpha}{2}+\rho+1, \frac{\nu-\mu-\alpha}{2} + \rho +1 \end{matrix}\right]\\[.2cm]
\times{}& {}_3 F_4 \left(\begin{matrix} \frac{1-\alpha}{2}+\rho, 1-\frac{\alpha}{2} + \rho, \rho \\ \rho+1 - \frac{\mu+\nu+\alpha}{2},\rho + 1 + \frac{\mu-\nu-\alpha}{2}, \rho+1 + \frac{\mu+\nu-\alpha}{2}, \rho+1 + \frac{\nu-\mu-\alpha}{2}\end{matrix}; c^2 z^2\right)\\[.2cm]
+{}&{}\frac{z^{\alpha-2\rho}}{2}\left(\frac{cz}{2}\right)^{\mu+\nu}\Gamma \left[\begin{matrix}\rho-\frac{\alpha+\mu+\nu}{2}, \frac{\alpha+\mu+\nu}{2}\\ \rho, \mu+1, \nu+1\end{matrix}\right] {}_3 F_4\left(\begin{matrix} \frac{1+\mu+\nu}{2}, 1+ \frac{\mu+\nu}{2}, \frac{\alpha+\mu+\nu}{2}\\ 1-\rho + \frac{\alpha+\mu+\nu}{2} , \mu+1, \nu+1, \mu+\nu+1\end{matrix}; c^2 z^2\right)
\end{align}
where $c>0$, $\mathrm{Re}\,z>0$, $\mathrm{Re}(\alpha+\mu+\nu)>0$ and $\mathrm{Re}(\alpha-2\rho)>1$.

- As you can see, the above formula is not concise.
- Are you sure there's nothing wrong with your **dimensions**?

Comment: What do you mean by 'dimension'?  The power of r and \mu?  By the way, which page of the book you mentioned are you refering to?